# Using a nightly TensorFlow build for training with Cloud ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

If I need to use a nightly TensorFlow build in a Cloud ML Engine training job, how do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

- Download a nightly build from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation.
  How to pick the right build:

  - use "Linux CPU-only" or "Linux GPU" depending on whether you need to use GPUs for training,
  - use the Python 2 build.
- Rename the .whl file, for example

  ```
  mv tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl \
     tensorflow-1.0.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  ```

  *(here we renamed the `cpu27mu` to `none`. Pip parses that part to detect whether a .whl package is suitable for a platform, but that particular name doesn't work on some older versions of pip)*
- Upload the .whl file to GCS and specify it as one of the `package_uris`
  when submitting a Cloud ML Engine training job.

Note that instead of using a nightly build you can also build TensorFlow from source as described in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources.