# Using tensorflow.contrib.data.Dataset in Cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Recently I changed my data pipeline in tensorflow from threading to a new Dataset api, which is pretty convenient once you want to validate your model each epoch.

I've noticed that [current runtime version of tensorflow in Cloud ML is 1.2](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/runtime-version-list). Nevertheless, I've tried to use [nightly build of tensorflow v1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148789/using-a-nightly-tensorflow-build-for-training-with-cloud-ml-engine), but pip installation fails with:

```
AssertionError: tensorflow==1.3.0 .dist-info directory not found
Command '['pip', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', '--no-deps', u'tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Does anyone succeeded with using tensorflow.cotrib.data.Dataset with Cloud ML engine?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:  create a setup.py file with the following content:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow==1.3.0']

setup(
    name='trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='Upgrading tf to 1.3')
```

more info on the setup.py file is available at: [Packaging a Training Application](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/packaging-trainer#to_include_additional_pypi_dependencies)